# Change a Mac Mission Control wallpaper using the terminal

Tags: terminal, spaces, mission-control

I can use Automater to change the wallpaper of the current "space" im in, but I can't tell it to change another space.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Note to self: try Built in Desktop pic folder option in pref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't automator, but works well for me.

In the space that you want to change the desktop, open **System Preferences** > **Desktop & Screen Saver** > Select the picture you want for that space/screen.

Comment: mmm, yeah wont work for me. I'm after a "live" type wallpaper which auto updates everytime a new image appears in a folder.